# facebook image not displaying when click like button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-like

i have looked at various other posts on SO, but nothing worked for me.

i have in head section:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.impressionable.me" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.impressionable.me/assets/mirror.png" />
```

when i click like button on my site, everything displays correctly except the **image**. i have also checked out [facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) for the url and this is what i get:

response code 206
Can't download  Could not retrieve data from URL.

Strangely enough, the debug page at the bottom displays the correct image? i am confused as to why this is happening? any thoughts?

Comment: Without knowing the URL there's no way to help you - this is is likely because facebook's crawler can't reach your page, is being served the wrong metadata or an error, or facebook has blocked the URL for spam  or security reasons

Comment: @Igy i have edited url above. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.impressionable.me It returns with a HTTP 200 response code and all the items are shown. Remember the scraper checks every 24 hours

> Facebook scrapes your page every 24 hours to ensure the properties are up to date. The page is also scraped when an admin for the Open Graph page clicks the Like button and when the URL is entered into the Facebook URL Linter. Facebook observes cache headers on your URLs - it will look at "Expires" and "Cache-Control" in order of preference. However, even if you specify a longer time, Facebook will scrape your page every 24 hours.

[image: Debugger]

[image: On Facebook]